# Looking for geo localization data of golf courses

Tags: data-request, geospatial, api, sports

I'm looking for free geo localization data of world wide golf courses. I can easily parse and store this information from several specialized websites... But I would like to find another way to get it (just don't want to have any copyright issues).

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

You could start with the 25000+ objects tagged with [leisure=golf_course](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/leisure=golf_course) on OpenStreetMap. To do this, you could extract the geolocations with GIS tools, or create a custom map like they did with [bicycle tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bicycle_tags_map). OSM data is [ODbL licensed](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright).

Answer (score 3):

geonames.usgs.gov has all the named features on US maps, including golf courses. They have some coverage of foreign names, too, but I have no experience with those.

Comment: nice resource (with lots of non-cryptic data for download)!