# Using Google Maps Data

Tags: licensing, geospatial

Is it possible to obtain a dataset of all search results in a google maps search? For example: if I want a list of all gas stations in Chicago, complete with addresses, store name, latitude-longitude coordinates etc.

Is such a data set against Google user agreement terms? I only plan on using the data for academic research questions.

Comment: Does Google Maps support on Spatial datasets and its related Weather dataset such as thematic layers of a location or region. If so, where can we get them. Such datasets help public on exactness of rainfall at a location, intensity of landslide at a location.

Comment: Sorry - can you clarify your question? Are you looking for geographic rainfall data? Maybe that might be better to post as a separate question.

Comment: I also recommend to use Open Street Maps. This is what we use in our Landing Pages, showing the position of bus and train stations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using the **[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)**.

Just for completeness sake: This is most definitely ***not open data***. For an open alternative, have a look at [Phil's answer about Open Street Maps](//opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/using-google-maps-data#4803).

If your usage complies with Google's terms depends on what exactly you plan to do with the data. I guess [section 10.1.3 of the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3) will be most relevant for you:

> (a) **No Unauthorized Copying, Modification, Creation of Derivative Works, or Display of the Content.** You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof except as explicitly permitted under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; (iii) creating mailing lists or telemarketing lists based on the Content; or (iv) exporting, writing, or saving the Content to a third party's location-based platform or service.
>
> (b) **No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content.** You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.
>
> (c) **No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content.** You must not use the Service in a manner that gives you or any other person access to mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, including but not limited to numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, visible map data, or places data (including business listings). For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).

Answer (score 3):

For licensing and ease-of-use purposes, you are better going with [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100). See, for example, these answers about how to use the data.

- [Extract data about golf courses](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1844/1511)
- [Restaurants in the EU](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3953/1511)
- [ATM locations in the UK](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4642/1511)
- [Embassies around the world](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4152/1511)

You can download all the OSM data ([instructions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data)) or use one of the several public APIs or prepacked databases ([details](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs)). Mapquest is one API provider using OSM data and with very generous free request quotas.

Comment: This is extremely useful. I checked out OSM, and it is a very good resource that I haven't used before. Thanks!