# List of European Hospitals and Health Clinics

Tags: data-request, medical, europe

I am looking for a overview on hospitals and medical services provided by the public (and also by the private) healthcare sector in Europe.

- public hospitals
- private hospitals and medical clinics ...

I am looking for all the European Countries.

Requirements for each item:

- name
- address
- postal code
- town
- street
- website
- (and email address)

Answer (score 3):

There might not be a database covering all countries of Europe (for instance the non-democratic country [Belarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus) does not publish much information). So if you need more data that OpenStreetMap has, you will probably need to go country-by-country. Below is the data for France.

The French government has created a website showing the list of all 4307 hospitals and clinics in France:

http://www.ScopeSante.fr

Click on "*Voir la liste des établissements*" to get the full list.

[image: hopitaux]

You will need to scrape that. Each hospital name has a link to [its detailed information page](http://www.scopesante.fr/fiches-detaillees/750150146/):

[image: hopital]

I have just sent them a message asking for a dump of the data. They replied to me saying that all of their data comes from the FINESS database, which is also maintained by the French government, and available online "*for private use*" and unfortunately does not have dump downloads, so that would mean scraping that:

[image: FINESS]

Comment: hello dear Nicolas - would be interesting to see a db-dump of the data - seems ot be a non-profit organization that is running the website. - look forward to hear from you - greetings

Answer (score 2):

Because you are looking for multiple countries, a good source of geo and meta data would be the [Open Street Map](http://osm.org/) project.

See, for example: `http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:healthcare`

> A key to tag all places that provide healthcare (are part of the healthcare sector).

You can use [overpass-turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo) to screen tags and keys, and then use [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/) to download data for those keys.

See [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4803/1511) for more info of how people are using OSM.

Answer (score 1):

hello butch miller hello philshem,

@ philshem: well said - i can second your ideas regarding the usage of openstreetmap. this is one of the best sources for gathering data.... 
so i wholeheartedly agree with you philshem.

i guess that butch miller benefits from usage overpass-turbo;  this is a great tool.

i just have tested it with this code

```
[adiff:"2014-07-01T00:00:00Z"];area[name="Argentina"][boundary=administrative]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];way(area.a)[amenity=hospital];);out center;
```

of ourse this is not european - but southern america - but i think butch you get a glimpse of what is meant.

just let us know how you like this ideas...

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for good dental clinic in eastern Europe, I deffinately recommend [Protezavimas-imlantavimas clinic][1]

[1]: https://www.protezavimas-implantavimas.lt/lt/ in Vilnius, Lithuania.